# Inconsistency in deserializing objects with Jackson streaming API when printing vs breakpoint debuging

Tags: java, json, api, jackson, streaming

I try to debug a java jackson objects deserialization.

If I put break point in my loop and looking into each of the token(element), it's totally different from what it prints out without stopping.
I am getting consistent result from printing, but the break point gives me random result.

My guess is, this streaming API comes with a buffer, when I put a break point there, the buffer overflowed and either oldest or newest message discarded.